# Microsoft Excel spreadsheet used as a computation engine called from code

Tags: ruby, excel, spreadsheet, ole

I have a MS Excel spreadsheet which does some complex computations. I'd like to create a script which will create a CSV file with the results obtained from the spreadsheet.

I could rewrite the logic from the spreadsheet in my programming language (for example Ruby, but I'm open to use a different language), but then I would have to update my code whenever someone changes the logic in the spreadsheet. Is it possible to use a MS Excel spreadsheet as a black box, a computation engine, which can be invoked from my code? Then I would only have write the CSV part and input data download in my code, the whole computation logic could stay in the spreadsheet and could be easily updated.

Ideally, I don't want to add any CSV generation or data download code to the spreadsheet, because it's used by domain-experts (not programmers). Additionally, I have to download some data from the Internet and pass it to the spreadsheet as the input values. I'd like to keep that part of the code externally, in a version control system like Git. One additional note is that the spreadsheet uses the Solver Excel plugin.

Any help how to do that would be very appreciated.

Thanks,
Michal

Comment: Don't you want to create the csv from Excel?

Comment: It is not clear to me why you would want to invoke the Excel workbook from some other language.  Unless I am missing something leave the users to operate the workbook in the normal way and add a BeforeClose Event to output the CSV file.  If you do not know VBA this will be a little difficult but I less difficult, I believe, than any other option.

Comment: Tony, I need to run the calculation periodically. I wanted to create a scheduled task which would be executed periodically by the system. The task would have to download some input data from the Internet and pass it to the spreadsheet. I'll update the question now. Thanks, Michal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To manipulate an Excel spreadsheet using Ruby, you may want to use win32ole

Here's a sample script:

```
data = [["Hello", "World"]]

# Require the WIN32OLE library
require 'win32ole'
# Create an instance of the Excel application object
xl = WIN32OLE.new('Excel.Application')
# Make Excel visible
xl.Visible = 1
# Add a new Workbook object
wb = xl.Workbooks.Add
# Get the first Worksheet
ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
# Set the name of the worksheet tab
ws.Name = 'Sample Worksheet'
# For each row in the data set
data.each_with_index do |row, r|
  # For each field in the row
  row.each_with_index do |field, c|
      # Write the data to the Worksheet
      ws.Cells(r+1, c+1).Value = field.to_s
  end
end
# Save the workbook
wb.SaveAs('workbook.xls')
# Close the workbook
wb.Close
# Quit Excel
xl.Quit
```

To work out more complicated code, just record a macro of what you want to do, and then look at the code of your macro, and convert it from VB into Ruby.

Comment: This's promising. Do you know if it's possible to execute an Excel add-in using OLE?